# 301 Redirecting posts without %postid% (just %post_name%) in permalink to ones with %post_name%_%postid%

Tags: posts, permalinks, redirect

Just wondering if its possible to redirect existing posts which are permalinks of just %post_name% to %post_name%-%postid% ?

Is there a plugin which can pick this up? Dont want to lose rankings on the content so would want it handled with legitimate 301 redirect.

Appreciate any advice if someone has had to deal with this before?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Redirection](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/) plugin do exactly what you are trying to do.